# SSLHandshake: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown Charles > iOS 10.3

Tags: ios, ios10

SSL errors on iOS 10.3 and above

SSLHandshake: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
You may need to configure your browser or application to trust the Charles Root Certificate. See SSL Proxying in the Help menu.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is because iOS 10.3 has enhanced the security of custom root CA:
Just go to Setting->General->About this phone->Trust Setting, and trust Charles certification

Answer (score 1):

This because of new security settings for iOS. You need to trust Charles certificate to remove the error. Settings > About > Certificate trust settings > Trust Charles root certificate (Toggle on)